# xslt 1.0 conversion of a data file

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am having to convert a data file from a previous version to an updated version.  I was going to use xslt for this conversion, completely naïve on this technology.  I have most of my fields getting converted over except for the first line(root?) of the file.
The start of my data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ABC schemaVersion="1.0" ism:office="A" ism:releasable="Y">
:
```

I cannot get the values for schemaVersion, ism:office or ism:releasable,
all tries returning null?
:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="ns0:ABC">
  <xsl:attribute name="schemaVersion" namespace="">
    <xsl:value-of select="@schemaVersion"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <Resource>
    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:ABC">
      <xsl:variable name="var1_cur" select="."/>
      <xsl:attribute name="ism:Bldg">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ism:office"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
```

Is there an XSLT 1.0 command that will parse? that first line?
Thank you for pondering.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct namespaces uris?

Comment: gtosto, yes I believe the uris are correct.  Using XMLSpy and debugging I cannot seem to get any of those entries from the root?  Is there a way to parse this?

Comment: you are selecting `ABC` nodes in the ns0 namespace while your XML shows that `ABC` has no namespace. Also, the `ism` namespace is not declared.